# What does [clearString.length -1 -i]) do in an if statement

Tags: javascript

In this code, what does `[clearString.length -1 -i]` do ?

```
function palindrome(str) {
    var clearString = str.toLowerCase().replace(/[^0-9a-z]/gi, '').split('');

    for (var i = 0; i < clearString.length/2; i++) {
        if (clearString[i] !== clearString[clearString.length -1 -i]) {  
            return false;
        } 
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Gets the index of the item before the one being accessed: Equivalent to `clearstring.length - (i + 1)`.

Comment: There is no such thing as an if loop...

Comment: @JeffRSon I took that out of there.

Comment: @krillgar: Okay - although their question is not quite related to the if statement...

Comment: @JeffRSon It relates enough as the OP is trying to determine how the equality for the if statement is being calculated.

Answer (score 1):

Actually `clearString.length -1 -i` calculates the index of the char that is as far from the end as `i` is from the beginning of the string.

Such it can be checked whether both characters are equal. If this is true for all chars you have a palindrome (read from the beginning it is the same as read from the end).

Comment: Ha! I was in the middle of writing my own, but your answer works.